# How do I disable some inspections for modules in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

In IntelliJ IDEA, I can disable some inspections for a class, method, or other units. I have a module in a project that's a library that I am not the only consumer of. I do not use all the methods in the library and consequently a large number are marked 'unused'. These are all false positives. I would like to disable these inspections for this module alone (ideally, I'd like to disable unused warnings for public/protected methods).

Is this possible? If so, how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to [define a custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scopes.html) and [configure the inspections' scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-inspection-for-different-scopes.html).

1. Go to `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Scope` and create a new scope. Include recursively all files, then exclude the given project library.
2. Then go to `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` and choose the inspections you want to disable for that project library, e.g. `Declaration redundancy -> Unused declaration`. In the severity settings (on the right side under "Description") choose your newly defined scope.

Per default the severity settings look like this (if the settings apply for all scopes):

[image: Inspection - Severity settings]

How it looks if the inspection is disabled for a scope named "Library Modules":

[image: Inspection - Severity settings - Inspection disabled for scope "Library Modules"]

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to apply this answer to my own project and I'm having trouble following your instructions. When you have time, do you think you could edit this answer to maybe be more specific and include screenshots? Thank you! I really need this! I've asked a similar question here if you'd like to just answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216514/intellij-disable-warnings-errors-for-a-single-module

Comment: I tried these exact steps and it ended up ignoring all "Unused declaration" warnings for all modules, not just the one I was trying to exclude.