# Android Studio - how to disable syntax checking for Android SDK Libs?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Each time we digging into the Android source code IntelliJ gets through that tedious process of syntax checking of the Core Libs source code.

[image: IntellJ oh my Gosh]

How to disable it? Let it just shows the google's code. I am unable to fix it.

Comment: I guess this is necessary to get all the nice navigation and search features.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692654/how-do-i-disable-some-inspections-for-modules-in-intellij-idea

Comment: nope, it doesn't help

IntelliJ just checks all library sources... WTF

https://i.imgur.com/7NupmM8.png

Only enabling the Power Safe Mode will fix it, but i can use Microsoft Visual Code instead then or just simple VIM

Comment: well, in other words: how to make **Highlighting Settings** turnded off Globally **by default** (but still keeping **Power Safe Mode** in disabled state) - https://i.imgur.com/RsHpMhm.png

Comment: What you are seeing are errors about unresolved classes, not about syntax problems. It looks like some issues with android databinding library you are using. Do you use Kotlin? Check similar threads about unresolved android databinding classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044756/2000323 , https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html Check also that the SDK you are using (in Project Structure) has databinding library components.